# Recommended approach to writing a client-side JavaScript application

Tags: javascript, web-applications, client-side

I'm considering learning JavaScript and I thought, what better way than to write an app! The idea is to make a simple school enrollment app, where the user would input enrolled student data and the app would automatically assign students to user-defined groups based on their enrollment score and group preferences.

Here are some basic ideas:

- Everything happens on the client side, I just provide the logic
- I don't want any of their data because it may be confidential/personal. I would consider gathering some usage statistics. To prevent them loosing their progress I would use Web Storage
- As output I want to produce CSV documents, one per defined group, each containing a list of assigned students
- Preferably the app will be a Wizard-like SPA.

Now for my question, I want to know 1) if there are any good resources (books, online trainings, etc.) about building such applications and 2) which libraries/frameworks are worth looking at. Please keep in mind I do want to learn the language, so I don't want tools that will do everything for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. There are many great resources out there. I would suggest knowing Javascript first and some good tutorials are hosted at codeacademy.com. If you would like more knowledge, get a book and practice a bit through their tutorials.
2. I would recommend looking up some of these: Backbone, Ember and AngularJS seem to be the most popular.  They are usually highly functional and easy to jump into with little javascript knowledge.They all usually include a type of routing, 2 way data-binding and a bit of extra goodies that make them unique. Explore them to find exactly what you need.

Angular: (link: https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_00) I would recommend going through the AngularJs tutorial (if you choose that framework). They teach you how to use node, karma and how their framework is set up with the seed data. This is maintained by Google so it may have a long future.

Ember.js: (link: http://emberjs.com/guides/) Has alot of tutorials and guides on how to use the framework.

Backbone.js: This is very popular and they have alot of real examples that is used by this framework.

Answer (score 0):

Ofcos there are. You should seriously consider angularjs. There are plenty tutorials that has examples on user management . look up Concrete's blog on angularjs. Its also a SPA framework.